# Removing HTML elements from javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to javascript and am looking to convert :

```
<script src="https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js"></script>
  <script>
     var miner = new CoinHive.Anonymous('KEY');
     miner.start();
  </script>
```

To javascript code which needs to be run server side. This is what I have so far but I cannot get it work:

```
function runminer() {
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = 'https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js';
   var miner = new script.CoinHive.Anonymous('KEY');
   script.miner.start()
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you're asking this question, you shouldn't be attempting to mine cryptocurrency. You need to output the created element **somewhere** in the DOM; how else will other people generate money for you?

Comment: What's your motivation for wanting to do that?

Comment: You can't execute a script without a script element. Notice, that script element doesn't create a namespace, `new script.CoinHive.Anonymous('KEY')` won't work even after appending the script into DOM.

Comment: What server-side JavaScript environment are you using? Node.js? Classic ASP? Netscape SSJS? Something else?

Comment: Your question, as it stands, is too broad. It can't really be answered without downloading a large JS file, un-minifying it, and figuring out how it works.

Comment: I know it sounds silly, but I don't know. I was told to test it out on jsfiddle.net in the javascript section and I cannot get it to work there.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're forgetting to add the script to the DOM, this should do the trick:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function() {
    var miner = new script.CoinHive.Anonymous('KEY');
    script.miner.start()
};
script.src = "https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It actually turns out that that javascript is being executed server side, not client side. Do you think there is a workaround?